# Can you connect a live frontend to a offline backend?

Tags: deployment, frontend, backend

I was wondering, is it possible to connect a deployed frontend to a offline backend on a local host on the same machine? Or a local frontend to a live backend?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'offline backend'.  Where is this frontend deployed to?

Comment: @ewong the frontend is deployed with Heroku, and the backend is being hosted on a local host using node.

Comment: Yes, you probably can do that.  Just set up port forwarding on your firewall/router to that machine in question.  Just make sure you've checked your backend for security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to connect a deployed frontend to an offline backend as it can only source data from an online source, but an offline frontend can source data from an online backend as long as the links to the data source or APIs are correctly placed. e.g a mongoDB database, can be posted or one can get data from the database using an offline frontend.